# Using "deleteMany" post middleware in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, middleware, mongoose-schema

In my Nodejs and Express app, I have a mongoose User schema, a Post schema and a Comment schema as follows:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    posts : [
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref  : 'Post' 
        }
    ]
});


const PostSchema = new Schema({
    author : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'User' 
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    text: String,
    comments : [
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref  : 'Comment' 
        }
    ],
});

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    author : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'User' 
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    text: String
});
```

I have coded the general CRUD operations for my User. When deleting my user,  I can easily delete all posts associated with that user using ***deleteMany***:

```
Post.deleteMany ({ _id: {$in : user.posts}});
```

To delete all the comments for all the deleted posts, I can probably loop through posts and delete all the comments, but I looked at mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-deleteMany) and it seems that **deleteMany** function triggers the **deleteMany middleware**. So In my Post schema, I went ahead and added the following after defining schema and before exporting the model.

```
PostSchema.post('deleteMany', async (doc) => {
    if (doc) {
        await Comment.deleteMany({
            _id: {
                $in: doc.comments
            }
        })
    }
})
```

When deleting user, this middleware is triggered, but the comments don't get deleted. I got the value of **doc** using *console.log(doc)* and I don't think it includes what I need for what I intend to do. Can someone tell me how to use the **deleteMany** middleware properly or if this is not the correct path, what is the most efficient way for me to delete all the associated comments when I delete the user and their posts?

Answer (score 2):

`deleteMany` will not give you access to the affected document because it's a query middleware rather than a document middleware (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware). Instead it returns the "Receipt-like" object where it tells it successfully deleted n objects and such.

In order for your hook to work as expected, you'll need to use something other than `deleteMany`, such as getting all of the documents (or their IDs), and loop through each one, using `deleteOne`.

Comment: this answer feels like a workaround. Wouldn't it be possible to get the _ids of all affected rows in the post deleteMany middleware?